# Helm dynamic variable based on Deployment name

Tags: kubernetes-helm, scaling

I have this Helm values:

```
applications_capacity:
  core:
    limit_cpu: 400m
    limit_memory: 512Mi
    request_cpu: 400m
    request_memory: 512Mi
  currency:
    limit_cpu: 400m
    limit_memory: 512Mi
    request_cpu: 400m
    request_memory: 512Mi
```

and I'm trying to reference values dynamically based on `metadata.name` with something like this:

```
requests:
{{- $ := . -}}
{{- $app_name := .Release.Name }}
  memory: {{ (get $.Values.applications_capacity $app_name).request_memory }}
```

but have and error:

`Error: ... at <$app_name>: can't evaluate field request_memory in type string`

I'm not very familiar with Helm expressions inside expressions, but even ChatGPT-4 didn't help a lot

Tried `index`, `get`, `range` expressions

Answer (score 0):

The [`get`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#get) extension function is documented as returning an empty string if the value doesn't exist.  The overall structure of your template code looks correct to me, but if `.Release.Name` isn't one of the specific values that's listed in the values file, you'll get pretty much exactly the error you describe.

It's possible the standard Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `index` function will return a more useful error, and be slightly more compact

```yaml
memory: {{ index .Values.applications_capacity .Release.Name "request_memory" }}
```

---

Another approach I would consider here is using a different set of values per environment or deployment, and not trying to embed the different environments into a single unified file.  For example, you can have an additional file

```yaml
# values.core.yaml
applications_capacity:
  limit_cpu: 400m
  limit_memory: 512Mi
  request_cpu: 400m
  request_memory: 512Mi
```

and apply that file of values when you're installing the chart

```bash
helm install -f values.core.yaml not-necessarily-core .
```

then your template code can avoid the dynamic lookup

```yaml
memory: {{ .Values.applications_capacity.request_memory }}
```

and you won't be tied to a preselected set of valid Helm release names.

Comment: for `index` expression it returns:
`at <index .Values.applications_capacity .Release.Name "request_memory">: error calling index: index of nil pointer`

and about different values It's a another good solution but if it's possible I would like to leave current logic

Comment: That again is the error that, whatever your Helm release name is, it isn't present in the fixed values file.

Answer (score 0):

So I answered question to myself:

```
{{- $app_name := "example" }}
resources:
   requests:
      memory: {{ index (index .Values.applications_capacity $app_name ) "limit_memory" }}
      cpu: {{ index (index .Values.applications_capacity $app_name ) "limit_cpu" }}
   limits:
      memory: {{ index (index .Values.applications_capacity $app_name ) "request_memory" }}
      cpu: {{ index (index .Values.applications_capacity $app_name ) "request_cpu" }}
```

need to use variable, because Helm can't reference "metadata.name" directly